# Is there a simpler way to unpivot a pandas table?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a pandas dataframe that gather spendings per sector in each country, which themselves depend on a certain ID.

```
    naf  |  loc   | ko_au | ko_fr | kd_us | kd_fr | ko_us
---------------------------------------------------------
0   21   |   22   |  13   | 15    |   17  |  13   |  19
1   26   |   14   |  13   | 24    |   24  |  19   |  17
2   23   |   28   |  11   | 26    |   10  |  15   |  28
3   12   |   23   |  22   | 14    |   26  |  25   |  12
```

I would like to unpivot them by country to get the following table:

```
    naf  |  loc  |  ct  | ko | kd
  --------------------------------------
0   21   |   22  |  au  | 13 | NaN
1   26   |   14  |  au  | 13 | NaN
2   23   |   28  |  au  | 11 | NaN
3   12   |   23  |  au  | 22 | NaN
4   21   |   22  |  fr  | 15 | 13
5   26   |   14  |  fr  | 24 | 19
6   23   |   28  |  fr  | 26 | 15
7   12   |   23  |  fr  | 14 | 25
8   21   |   22  |  us  | 19 | 17
9   26   |   14  |  us  | 17 | 24
10  23   |   28  |  us  | 28 | 10
11  12   |   23  |  us  | 12 | 26
```

Below is the code that I have written so far. It's quite ugly, it works in this case but when I scale it up to a 156 x 1510 matrix it no longer does. I am sure there is something simpler and faster to be done in order to achieve a better result. Would you have an idea?

```
naf = np.random.randint(low=10, high=30, size=7)
x = np.random.randint(low=10, high=30, size=7)
y = np.random.randint(low=10, high=30, size=7)
z = np.random.randint(low=10, high=30, size=7)
df = pd.DataFrame([naf, x, y, z], columns = ['naf', 'loc','ko_au', 'ko_fr', 'kd_us', 'kd_fr', 'ko_us'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
datadict = {}
data = []
colspec = list(set([i[:-3] for i in df.columns[2:]]))
colsprime = df.columns[:2]
for i in colspec:
    datadict[i] = {}
    df_trans = pd.DataFrame()
    for j in df.columns[2:]:
        if i in j:
            for k in colsprime:
                datadict[i][k] = df[k]
            datadict[i]['ct'] = j[-2:]
            datadict[i][i] = df[j]
            if df_trans.empty:
                df_trans = pd.DataFrame(datadict[i])
            else:
                df_trans = df_trans.append(pd.DataFrame(datadict[i]), ignore_index = True)
    data.append(df_trans.iloc[:, 0:])
    
for i in data:
    if df1.empty:
        df1 = i
    else:
        df1 = df1.merge(i, how = 'outer', left_on=list(colsprime)+['pays'], right_on=list(colsprime)+ ['ct'])
```

Comment: Have you tried the dataframe `melt` function?

Comment: You need [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html)